# Build optionally layouts in NextJS by detecting the browser URL value

Tags: reactjs, next.js

all I would try to make some optional layout in NextJS. My problem is that I have found some method to check the browser URL then serve content according to these URL. But by this way the server content an browser content are no longer identical, hence the schema breaks.

Here an snippet of my trial:

```
export default ({children, title = 'title' }) => {
var 

contact = false;
    if (exenv.canUseDOM ){ if (window.location.href==="http://localhost:4000/contact" ) { contact= true}; } 
else {const contact = false};
    if (contact){ return(  <div>Hey it is contact ! </div> ) } 
else {  // return  normal layout
```

My console returns me predictably:

> Warning: Text content did not match. Server:

So... I'm wondering if I have to make some custom settings on a custom NextJS server to grant the backend/frontend behaviors?

Or maybe there is a less expensive solution in the area?

Any hint would be great,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove that warning, it is appear because you just render that layout from client side, so there is a different between layout rendered by server and layout rendered by client.

I don't know what variable exenv.canUseDOM is, but you can use `process.browser` to detect if the current process is server side rendering or not.

Comment: Thanks, currently I'm using getInitialProps to get the first URL entered in address bar but seems the component is first rendered one time then the getInitialProps methods occurs, then the component is rerendered with the correct layout. This creates a slight flash with the standard layout then the customized layout appears, and it is very ugly obviously, so I would neutralize this tiny layout-lagging flash.